# Default values for query parameters

Tags: karate

Please forgive me if my question does not make sense.

What im trying to do is to inject in values for query parameters

```
GET1 File
Scenario:

Given path 'search'
And param filter[id] = id (default value or variable from another feature file)

POST1 File
Scenario:
def newid = new id made by a post call
def checkid = read call(GET1) {id : newid}
```

like if one of my feature files creates a new id then i want to do a get call with the above scenario. therefore i need a parameter there which takes in the new id.

On the other hand if i do not have an id newly created or the test creating it is not part of the suite. i want to still be able to run the above mentioned scenario but this time it has a default value to it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please elaborate a bit on the question? I'm afraid it's not quite clear.

Comment: what i mean by variable from another feature file, something similar to the my-signin.feature documentation

Comment: @dferenc  
Consider the scenario where i have this get call (lets call GET1). which takes in an id and gives me result. the Id goes in as url query parameter `www.example.com/?id=23`

Now i have another feature file that does a post call (lets call it POST1), and after that it gives me a new id. now i want to run GET1 again with the new id from POST1. so how do i inject this new value?

what im trying to do is this.

POST1
code to create new id
def checkcode = call read(GET1) {id = new id}

Comment: first time using stackoverflow. please ignore the noobness
writing out the code that i was stating in the above comment
`POST1 file`
`def newid = example code here that gets me new id`
`def checkid = read call (GET1) {id = newid}`

the newid gets injected into `param id` part of the GET1 file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `param` use [`params`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#keywords-that-set-multiple-key-value-pairs-in-one-step). It is designed so that any keys with null values are ignored.

After the `null` is set on the first line below, you can make a [`call`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#call) to another feature, and overwrite the value of `criteria`. If it still is `null`, no params will be set.

```
* def criteria = null
Given path 'search'
And params { filter: '#(criteria)' }
```

There are multiple other ways to do this, also refer to this set of examples for data-driven search params: [`dynamic-params.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/search/dynamic-params.feature)

The doc on [conditional logic](https://github.com/intuit/karate#conditional-logic) may also give you some ideas.

Comment: I tried. but since im new and not a high enough level, stack overflow is not giving me those options.

Comment: but i made this the answer!